# In-app Billing onActivityResult() is not called but purchase successed

Tags: android, in-app-billing, onactivityresult

I use the code of **"trivialdrive"** sample of in-app billing V3, and I purchase my product successfully.  Log shows succeeded:
07-24 10:50:36.314 D/Finsky  ( 4414): [1] PurchaseFragment.succeed: Purchase succeeded

But after come back to my own activity, onActivityResult() method is not called.
After that, i use another account to buy product , no matter what i do (cancle or buy), the method is still not called.
 I add below to my AndroidManifest, but in sample there are no Class BillingService,BillingReceiver. I doult Does it cause my problem.

```
    <receiver android:name="BillingReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.android.vending.billing.IN_APP_NOTIFY" />
            <action android:name="com.android.vending.billing.RESPONSE_CODE" />
            <action android:name="com.android.vending.billing.PURCHASE_STATE_CHANGED" />
              <action android:name="SENT_SMS_ACTION"  />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver> -->
```

**I'm in China where many strange problems will happen as you know.**

Comment: You don't need a receiver in V3. But I also have this problem with onActivityResult being called...

Answer (score 0):

Now i have deleted code above and the method is still not called after purchase successfully.
When i search answers , i find a new information as below:
**Most important for apps that sell in-app products, the new UI offers a dramatically simplified, dialog-based purchase flow that lets users buy your products without leaving the context of the app. Your app remains active and visible behind the purchase dialogs. When the purchase is complete, users return directly to the place they left, without your app having to reconstruct its state. It’s especially powerful when combined with In-app Billing v3, providing a faster and more reliable purchase flow.**

so now i doubt is it nature that my activity does not call onActivityResult() because of in-app billing offers **a dialog-based purchase**?